# python : best way of splitting ref IDs to their own rows

Tags: python

this is a 2 part question: 
1) how do i split the ref ids to their own rows. 
2) by splitting the ref ids, can i still use them as unique idenifiers with the task ID or do i need to create a 3rd columne for the primary key.

- Given the sample data set 
  [image]
- As far as an approach:

  1. I was thinking of loading a csv into a dictionary
  2. check 'BR Ref ID' value has more than one id and splitting it,
  3. Insert new rows with the found 'BR Ref ID' with original 'Task Req ID', 'New or Change', 'Asset(s)' and 'workflow'
  4. delete original row somehow << which is where I'm being stumped
  5. regarding 2 above.. what should i use as a unique idenifier as this data will be loaded back into a database of some kind.

Comment: Have you tried `openpyxl` package? It's quite convenient in terms of manipulating excel files. There's functionality to merge and un-merge cells as well.

Comment: This seems like something that could easily be done in excel, maybe without VBA

Comment: You get the dataset from Excel, Html table or else?

Comment: dataset is from an application which can export to csv.  i'm looking to automate the process using python. I could use VBA but i'm trying to schedule the task using MS task scheduler.